# From `=> T` to `() => T` and back again

Tags: scala, bytecode, callbyname, invokedynamic, pass-by-name

As parameters of types `=> T` and `() => T` are both `Function0`, I always naively assumed that conversion from one to another is a noop. It seems however, that while true for `(=>T) => (() => T)`, the other direction `(() => T) => (=> T)` results in wrapping the execution of the function in a `invokedynamic` lambda - at least as far as I can read the byte code.

1. Why?
2. How can I make it stop?

Comment: Related: https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/make-by-name-parameters-just-sugar-syntax-rather-than-actual-types/5228